# What does 「ふうに」 exactly mean?

Tags: translation, words

Just found a sentence:

> そんなふうに笑い飛ばす人は死ねばよかった。

I tried to find what it means in dictionary but to no avail, so what does it mean and how do you use it whether in daily conversation or literature works?

Comment: Search for 「そんな風に」 instead.

Comment: [http://jisho.org/search/そんなふうに](http://jisho.org/search/そんなふうに)

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of web-based resources to use in case you want to find the meaning/translation.

As being stated in comments, [jisho](http://jisho.org) is a great tool to do fulfill your needs in Japanese language.

You can search for the sentence [directly](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%9D%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA%E9%A2%A8%E3%81%AB), and then go through each word to understand the whole meaning. Not to mention, you can distinguish the word that you are looking for.

If you are looking for the specific word 「そんな風に」 (in this case), [search](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%9D%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA%E9%A2%A8%E3%81%AB) for it. The translation will be: in that manner; like that.

Comment: i disagree, jisho is an OKAY tool. people have greatly contributed to it but i have seen so many errors that could throw learners' memorizations off. I recommend just reading and using it in general cases when you have absolutely no other sources of reference.

Comment: This does not answer the question, but only provides a link to a dictionary definition. And I agree with David, Jisho.org is not the best resource out there. It is convenient but contains many errors.